# Authentication logs monitoring GCP

Tags: authentication, logging, google-cloud-platform

How can I monitor the authentication logs on the Google cloud platform?

For example, to check if someone has tried to make unauthorized access.

Comment: Can you precise on which product?

Answer (score 1):

With Admin Activity audit logs you will be able to answer the questions of "who did what, where, and when?" **within** your Google Cloud resources. It provides the following audit logs for each Cloud project, folder, and organization:

- Admin Activity audit logs
- Data Access audit logs
- System Event audit logs
- Policy Denied audit logs

You can obtain more information on [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit), It will be useful to see all the events that happen into your projects, but it might not be useful for the information you want to see.

Nevertheless, there is a tool [Event Threat Detection](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-security-sources#etd) that uses log data from inside your systems and when a threat is detected, Event Threat Detection writes a Finding to Security Command Center and to a Cloud Logging project.

For example:
Event Threat Detection detects brute force of password authentication SSH by examining syslog logs for repeated failures followed by a success.
But this feature is available only for Security Command Center Premium tier.

On the other hand you mentioned  that you have some VM instances and want to prevent attacks.

I recommend you to check the following documentation: [Securely connecting to VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely)
There are several methods for protecting services on VMs with external IP addresses explained in this document, including [Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#firewalls), [HTTPS and SSL](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#https-and-ssl), [port forwarding over SSH](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#port-forwarding-over-ssh), and [SOCKS proxy over SSH](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#socks-proxy-over-ssh).

For example, by creating firewall rules, you can restrict all traffic to a network or target machines on a given set of ports to specific source IP addresses.

Comment: I have some instances in my cloud and I want to prevent attacks, for example a bruteforce. To do this I would need the logs to be available on Cloud Logging. Is Admin Activity audit logs right for me?

Comment: @Unirc Now your question is more clear. 
I have updated my answer (basically I create a new one) with information you might find useful.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, you were very clear